# My xml is not being displayed anything( not even text) in IE even when there is no error from what I see

Tags: xml, xslt

I could not get my xml file to display on IE. I've already linked the xml file with the xsl file.The xml file display the raw xml code if I do not include the link to xsl. But when I add in the link, it displayes a blank page again. I have completely no idea why it is not displaying. Any help is appreciated!!!

My xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="part3.xsl"?>
<forecast queryTime="30/7/2021 14:10:20" queryLocation="Singapore">
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210617">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>6</month>
    <date>17</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Thu</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Considerable clouds</overall>
    <overallCode>cloudy</overallCode>
    <highest>29</highest>
    <lowest>19</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210612">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>6</month>
    <date>12</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Sat</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Cloudy with a thunderstorm</overall>
    <overallCode>thunderstorm</overallCode>
    <highest>28</highest>
    <lowest>23</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210709">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>7</month>
    <date>09</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Fri</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>A morning shower, then rain</overall>
    <overallCode>rain</overallCode>
    <highest>29</highest>
    <lowest>23</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210601">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>6</month>
    <date>01</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Tue</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Partly sunny</overall>
    <overallCode>partlySunny</overallCode>
    <highest>31</highest>
    <lowest>28</lowest>
  </weather>
  <weather yyyymmdd="20210802">
    <year>2021</year>   
    <month>8</month>
    <date>02</date>
    <dayOfWeek>Mon</dayOfWeek> 
    <overall>Plenty of sunshine</overall>
    <overallCode>sunny</overallCode>
    <highest>35</highest>
    <lowest>24</lowest>
  </weather>
</forecast>
```

My xsl file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/forecast">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Part 3</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="queryLocation"/>  [<xsl:value-of select="@queryTime"/>]</h1>
                <ul>
                  <xsl:for-each select="weather">
                    <li>
                      <xsl:value-of select="year" /> 
                      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="month" />
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="date" />
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
                      <xsl:value-of select="dayOfWeek" />
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
                      <xsl:value-of select="overall" />
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
                      <xsl:value-of select="overallCode" />
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
                      <xsl:value-of select="higheset" />
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
                      <xsl:value-of select="lowest" />
                    </li>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: did you check browser console for errors? Perhaps the xslt file cannot be found and downloaded

Comment: ohhh how do i check that ?

Comment: IE developer tools can be openend by pressing F12 on the desired page, then look for network tab

Comment: do you open the file from a folder or a  by url from a server?

Comment: OHOH it showed ==> Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Users/Aner/Desktop/A2/part3.xsl from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Aner/Desktop/A2/A2.xml. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.

Comment: from a folder on my desktop

Comment: I so far never noticed that kind of security warning with IE. So which IE version on which Windows version is that excactly? And as the message says "from frame with`, is the XML file loaded in a top level window of IE or in an iframe or frame?

Comment: It is version 95.0.1020.40 on windows 11. And so sorry I don't understand the second question. My xml file is in a folder on the desktop and my IE is on my desktop.

Comment: Are you sure you use IE (Internet Explorer) and not Edge? Edge has that version number. And Edge is based on Chromium, like Google Chrome, and there indeed the ability to run XSLT in local file system based XML documents linking to the XSLT with `xml-stylesheet` has been disabled years ago. So if you are on Windows and need that feature make sure you use Internet Explorer and not Edge.

Comment: OHHHH omg i thought they were the same thing LOL so sorry for this THank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Accessing linked files from filesystem is limited in modern browsers due to security issues.

For chromium based browser there seems to be a workaround using

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

cmdline option.

Or just put the files on a webserver, then it should work.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70088

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to solve it T^T how do I put files on a webserver? I don't have a server though. I also don't understand how to use the cmdline option ahhh. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: what's the use case? for using xml/xslt to create web pages for displaying in a browser, there's a web server. For local use I'd recommend a standalone xslt processor like [msxml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML) or [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net)

Comment: ohhhh tks bro i'll try it out